# Melting Transformation

Tags: python, excel, powerbi, powerquery

I work with financial files that are organized with dates as the columns.
[Example Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cQKWW.png).
However, I need to transform a table like this to have column names like this: Name, Date, Apples, Oranges. How would you do this using Python, Power Query, or Excel?

| Type | Name | Jan-21 | Feb-21 | Mar-21 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Apples | John | $1.20 | $1.05 | $1.65 |
| Oranges | John | $1.42 | $1.15 | $1.77 |
| Apples | Jim | $1.60 | $1.15 | $1.85 |
| Oranges | Jim | $1.62 | $1.45 | $1.37 |

I'm wanting the table to look like this:

| Name | Dates | Apples | Oranges |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John | Jan-21 | $1.20 | $1.42 |
| John | Feb-21 | $1.05 | $1.15 |
| Jim | Jan-21 | $1.60 | $1.62 |
| Jim | Feb-21 | $1.15 | $1.45 |

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] with your sample input as text, not as an image or link, your expected output, and code or a description of what you've tried so far based on your own research, so that we can better understand how to help

Comment: @G.Anderson - just manually added part of the table. StackOverflow limited what I could add because it's my first post. Hence the picture...

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Solved my own problem using Power Query (within Power BI). I just unpivoted all columns other than Type and Name. Then pivot the Type column using the new "Value" column. Also, this is apparently called melting which I wasn't familiar with.